# Adding Height and Width to Src of Multiple img tags

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html code:

```
<p>adfa</p>
<p><img src="http://localhost:27756//download.jpg" alt="" width="282" height="179" /></p>
<p>adfa</p>
<p><img src="http://localhost:27756/Summit 2013-5.jpg" alt="" width="358" height="358" /></p>
<p>adfa</p>
```

Now I want to add height and width of each image to its src. How can I do that? I am very new to jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function addDimensionsToSrc(){
            jQuery("img").each(function(idx,el){
                el.src = el.src + "?height=" + el.height + "&width=" + el.width;    
            });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>adfa</p>
        <p><img src="http://localhost:27756//download.jpg" alt="" width="282" height="179" /></p>
        <p>adfa</p>
        <p><img src="http://localhost:27756/Summit 2013-5.jpg" alt="" width="358" height="358" /></p>
        <p>adfa</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: create an html file with the above code, run it in a browser, hit F12 to open the console, and run the javascript line by line.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
$('img').each(function() {

alert($(this).attr('src'));

$(this).css('width',500);
$(this).css('height',500);

});
```

If you want to add to `img` attribute you can do like:

```
$('img').each(function(i) {

alert('OLD:Width for image at index '+i+' is '+$(this).attr('width'));
alert('OLD:height for image at index '+i+' is '+$(this).attr('height'));

$(this).attr('width',500);
$(this).attr('height',500);

alert('NEW:Width for image at index '+i+' is '+$(this).attr('width'));
alert('NEW:height for image at index '+i+' is '+$(this).attr('height'));
});
```

Demo Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eqr5s9ac/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("img").each(function(idx, e) {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr('src') + '?width=' + $(this).attr('width') + '&height=' + $(this).attr('height'));
});
```

fiddle here:  https://jsfiddle.net/y794tazy/

To use the true images width and height (since this can be different than what the attributes are set at), you could do this:

```
$("img").each(function(idx, e) {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr('src') + '?width=' + $(this).width() + '&height=' + $(this).height());
});
```

Comment: I got the idea. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help.  If you want to use the true images width and height instead of what the attributes say, you could use `$(this).width()` and `$(this).height()`.